# Json Send/Post error in blackberry

Tags: json, blackberry

I want to send JSON request through HTTPConnection but i am getting error when i am trying to get the response code.
Here is my code...

```
public void sendrequest(String url)throws IOException, JSONException
{
        JSONObject postObject = new JSONObject();

        postObject.put("method", method);

        postObject.put("params", Parameters);

        HttpConnection c = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);

        c.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);

            c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

            c.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + (postObject.toString().length() - 2));
            c.setRequestProperty("method", method);

            c.setRequestProperty("params", Parameters);

            rc = c.getResponseCode();

            if (rc != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK){

                throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + rc);
            }
}
```

i get this code from [Send JSON request from blackberry](http://%22https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339656/send-json-request-from-blackberry-application%22%20but%20never%20understood%20what%20is%20value%20of%20the%20variable) used in  postObject.put("method", method);

Comment: postObject.put("method", method); in this, "method" - is the field name and method - is the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `method` is a `String` to specify the request method `HttpConnection.GET` or `HttpConnection.POST`.

You have to specify it like:

```
c.setRequestProperty("method", HttpConnection.GET);
```

or

```
c.setRequestProperty("method", HttpConnection.POST);
```

You can use [c.setRequestMethod()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html#setRequestMethod%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339656/send-json-request-from-blackberry-application)

Comment: Thanks buddy.. but this code is still not working i get another code using ConnectionFactory and ConnectionDescriptor and HttpConnection too and this code is working fine.... Here is the working code

Comment: That's fine, but the above code is also supposed to work... Did you add connection parameters (`"deviceside=false"`, `"interface=wifi"`) with the `url` to specify the connection method? See more about that [here](http://testberry.blogspot.com/2011/05/blackberry-connectivity-issues.html)